# Exact ground state energy of the noninteracting one-dimensional Bose Hubbard model?

Tags: condensed-matter, bosons, ground-state, bose-hubbard-model

The Hamiltonian of Bose-Hubbard model reads as
$$
H = -J\sum_{<i,j>}a_i^\dagger a_j + h.c. + \frac{U}{2}\sum_i n_i(n_i - 1)
$$
In the non-interacting case where $U=0$, what is the ground state energy for the one-dimensional ($\sum_{<i,j>}a_i^\dagger a_j = \sum_i a_i^\dagger a_{i+1}$) case with periodic boundary conditions (for an N-site model, $a_{N+1} = a_1$), if an exact result exists ?

Comment: When $U=0$ this is just the [tight binding model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a comment, this is a simple tight binding. However the concrete application might be confusing at the beginning. I suggest you perform a Fourier transformation of the bosonic operators, namely:
$$
a_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k e^{i k x_j} a_k,
$$
where $x_j$ is the spatial coordinate of the $j$-th site. The periodic boundary condition implies $k = 2\pi n/N$, where $n = 0, 1, ..., N-1$.
If you make use of the following definition of the Kronecker delta function
$$
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{j} e^{i (k-p) x_j} = \delta_{k,p}
$$
you end up with the final result
$$
H = \sum_k \varepsilon_k a^{\dagger}_k a_k,
$$
where $\varepsilon_k = -2J\cos(k s)$ is the energy-momentum dispersion relation of the lattice, $s$ being the lattice spacing, let's say $s=1$ for simplicity.

In momentum space the problem has been simplified a lot, since we have found the energy states available for a single boson ($\varepsilon_k$).
Now we have to exploit the fact that the particles are bosons: a consequence of the bosonic algebra is that an arbitrary amount of bosons can live in the same single particle energy state, so in the zero-temperature case, when thermal fluctuations are frozen, all the bosons will occupy the lowest single particle energy state, which is the zero momentum mode $\varepsilon_0 = -2J$, so the total ground state energy is $E_0 = -2JN$. By the way, the ground state can be formally written from the vacuum state $| 0 \rangle$ by placing all the particles in the $k=0$ state: $| \psi \rangle = (a^{\dagger}_{k=0})^N | 0 \rangle$ up to a normalization factor.

Comment: Ok thank you for your clear answer !

Answer (score 0):

As already commented when you only have the hopping term the model reduces to a tight-binding model that one can easily diagonalize switching to momentum space.

Consider for example PBC for 2 sites, then you'll diagonalize your model obtaining two energy levels $\pm 2J$. You can see it like a free-bosons model where a certain boson has a positive chemical potential and the other a negative one. You should know that free-bosons cannot have a positive chemical potential, the model would favor to have as many bosons as possible (infinite) in the lower energy state and this is physically meaningless.